Replace EDID monitor description
A 43" 4K TCL Android TV is incorrectly being reported as XXX 55" by it's EDID information.
Output from ll /sys/class/drm/*/edid:
-r--r--r-- 1 root root 0 Jun 24 19:01 /sys/class/drm/card0-DP-1/edid
-r--r--r-- 1 root root 0 Jun 27 06:16 /sys/class/drm/card0-DP-2/edid
-r--r--r-- 1 root root 0 Jun 24 19:01 /sys/class/drm/card0-eDP-1/edid
-r--r--r-- 1 root root 0 Jun 27 06:16 /sys/class/drm/card0-HDMI-A-1/edid
-r--r--r-- 1 root root 0 Jun 27 06:16 /sys/class/drm/card0-HDMI-A-2/edid

The June 27 records are misleading and should be deleted. However, it's immaterial to this question.

Output from: for p in /sys/class/drm/*/status; do con=${p%/status}; echo -n "${con#*/card?-}: "; cat $p; done:
DP-1: connected
DP-2: disconnected
eDP-1: connected
HDMI-A-1: disconnected
HDMI-A-2: disconnected

HDMI-A-1 is misleading because 50" TV is managed by Nvidia 970M and not the Intel Integrated GPU which only manages DP-1 (43" TV) and eDP-1 (17" laptop built in display).

Output from: xrandr | grep " connected":
HDMI-0 connected 1920x1080+0+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 1107mm x 623mm
eDP-1-1 connected primary 1920x1080+3870+2160 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 382mm x 215mm
DP-1-1 connected 3840x2160+1920+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 1209mm x 680mm

The -1-1 suffix is annoying as it should be -1 only. However, that is immaterial to this question. DP-1-1 dimensions of 1209mm x 680mm (55") are out to lunch. The dimensions should be 941mm x 529mm (43").

Relevant output from: sudo get-edid -b 4 | parse-edid:
Section "Monitor"
    Identifier "Beyond TV"
    ModelName "Beyond TV"
    VendorName "XXX"
    # Monitor Manufactured week 20 of 2019
    # EDID version 1.3
    # Digital Display
    DisplaySize 1210 680

The variables VendorName and DisplaySize are the shiny objects being chased.

Summary
It is assumed that xrandr is the wrong way of correcting the monitor details. Linux allows changing the EDID data and it assumed this must be done before GNOME desktop is loaded by systemd?
I found a possible GitHub solution: How to modify physical display size in EDID however, maybe something easier and more robust exists.
How can EDID VendorName be changed from XXX to TCL and DisplaySize changed from 1210 680 (55") to 941 x 529 (43")?
